# Is my ftp issue a coding error or credentials error?

Tags: asp.net, ftp

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and I am trying, for the first time, to ftp a file through the app. There are several examples on the net. This one made the most sense to me. Being unsure of the actual local it will be going, right now, I decided to FTP it right back to my local host, figuring I have the credential so it would be a good test. However, it is failing with the following error: "Unable to connect to the remote server".

```
public void FTPFile()
        {
            string CompleteFTPPath = "ftp://localhost//WebSite1/test.txt";
            string CompleteLocalPath = "C:\\test_file.txt";

        //Create a FTP Request Object and Specfiy a Complete Path 
        FtpWebRequest reqObj = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(CompleteFTPPath);

        reqObj.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        reqObj.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<my user name>", "<my pw>");

        FileStream streamObj = File.OpenRead(CompleteLocalPath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[streamObj.Length];

        streamObj.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        streamObj.Close();
        streamObj = null;

        reqObj.GetRequestStream().Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        reqObj = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the ftp server is listening on the localhost (127.0.0.1) and not just on it's network ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the basics.
Have you started a FTP server on your localhost?
Can you use a standard FTP client (either ftp in commandline or a downloaded ftp client like filezilla).

Answer (score 0):

`unable to connect to remote server` typically means exactly that; no server responded or you couldn't reach the server.

Do you have a local ftp server running? What happens when you point your web browser to **ftp://localhost/**" ?

To answer your question: No, probably not. :-)